# Boxes are not well placed in the given layout - Ludo (html,css)

Tags: html, css, web, flexbox, media-queries

[image]

As you can see mid layout of this board is not well placed. Please anyone set this, and some some media-queries so it can also run on Mobile devices. Suggest Something to Make it right placed.

Without media queries, it looks like this:

[image]

**My Code:**

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 985px;
  /* font-size: 9.85rem; */
  /* height:150vh; */
}

.container {
  margin: 0 30%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* padding: auto; */
  /* border: 2px solid green; */
  display: flex;
}

.first-box {
  /* border: 2px solid red; */
  width: 38%;
  /* height: 33.3%; */
  /* height: 30vh; */
  background-color: lime;
  /* position: relative;
    z-index: 1; */
  display: flex;
}

.box-1-parent {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content:space-around; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  /* margin: ; */
  width: 60%;
  /* left: 18%; */
  height: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  /* position:relative; */
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.box-1 {
  /* padding: ;     */
  background-color: lime;
  width: 33%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 34%;
  /* align-items: ; */
  /* border: 2px solid black; */
  /* margin: auto ; */
}

.sec-box {
  /* width: 7.5vw; */
  width: 19%;
  height: 30vh;
  /* height: 197.1px; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.smallbox {
  width: 34.5%;
  /* width: 2.5vw; */
  height: 5vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.third-box {
  width: 38%;
  /* width: 15vw; */
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  /* position: relative;
    z-index: 1; */
  display: flex;
}

.box-3-parent {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content:space-around; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  /* margin: ; */
  width: 60%;
  /* left: 18%; */
  height: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  /* position:relative; */
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 33%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 34%;
}

.second-box {
  width: 38%;
  /* width: 15vw; */
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: red;
  /* position: relative;
    z-index: 1; */
  display: flex;
}

.box-2-parent {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content:space-around; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  /* margin: ; */
  width: 60%;
  /* left: 18%; */
  height: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  /* position:relative; */
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 33%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 34%;
}

.forth-box {
  width: 38%;
  /* width: 15vw; */
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: aqua;
  /* position: relative;
    z-index: 1; */
  display: flex;
}

.box-4-parent {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content:space-around; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
  /* margin: ; */
  width: 60%;
  /* left: 18%; */
  height: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  /* position:relative; */
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.box-4 {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 33%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 34%;
}

.mid-box {
  /* width: 100%; */
  /* height: 38%; */
  height: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* margin: 0; */
  /* border-collapse:collapse; */
}

.win-area {
  font-size: 3.7vh;
  /* height: 15vh;
    width: 7.5vw; */
  border-color: yellow aqua red lime;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 3%;
  color: blueviolet;
  text-decoration: underline blueviolet wavy 5px;
}

.line-top {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.line-mid {
  background-color: lime;
}

.line-mid-rgt {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.line-down {
  background-color: red;
}

.github {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  width: 100px;
  /* margin: auto; */
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Other way to make border triangle */


/*

.contain-triangles {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

.triangle-right {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 45px solid transparent;
border-left: 45px solid lime;
border-bottom: 45px solid transparent;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 5.2px;
} 

.triangle-up {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 45px solid transparent;
border-right: 45px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 45px solid red;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 5.2px;
}

.triangle-left {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-right: 45px solid aqua;
border-bottom: 45px solid transparent;
border-top: 45px solid transparent;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 5.2px;
}

.triangle-down {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 45px solid transparent;
border-right: 45px solid transparent;
border-top: 45px solid yellow;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 5.2px;
}

*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ludocss.css">

</head>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Let's Play Ludo </h1>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-box">
    <div class="box-1-parent">
      <div class="box-1"></div>
      <div class="box-1"></div>
      <div class="box-1"></div>
      <div class="box-1"></div>
      <!-- <div class="box-1"></div>
                <div class="box-1"></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sec-box">
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-top"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-top"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-top"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-top"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-top"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-top"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="third-box">
    <div class="box-3-parent">
      <div class="box-3"></div>
      <div class="box-3"></div>
      <div class="box-3"></div>
      <div class="box-3"></div>
      <!-- <div class="box-1"></div>
                <div class="box-1"></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="container">
  <div class="mid-box-parent">

  </div>
  <div class="mid-box">
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="win-area">
      <!-- <div class="row2-col2"> -->
      <!-- add triangular effect using html and css -->
      <div class="contain-triangles">
        <div class="triangle-right"></div>
        <div class="triangle-up"></div>
        <div class="triangle-left"></div>
        <div class="triangle-down"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- </div> -->
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="smallbox" id="box-19"></div>
            <div class="smallbox" id="box-20"></div>
            <div class="smallbox" id="box-21"></div>
            <div class="smallbox" id="box-22"></div>
            <div class="smallbox" id="box-23"></div>
            <div class="smallbox" id="box-24"></div>
            <div class="smallbox" id="box-25"></div>
            <div class="smallbox" id="box-26"></div>
            <div class="smallbox" id="box-27"></div> -->
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid-rgt"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid-rgt"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid-rgt"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid-rgt"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid-rgt"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1 line-mid-rgt"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
    <div class="smallbox smallbox-1"></div>
  </div>

</div>




<div class="container">
  <div class="second-box">
    <div class="box-2-parent">
      <div class="box-2"></div>
      <div class="box-2"></div>
      <div class="box-2"></div>
      <div class="box-2"></div>
      <!-- <div class="box-1"></div>
                <div class="box-1"></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sec-box">
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-down"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-down"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-down"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-down"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-down"></div>
    <div class="smallbox line-down"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
    <div class="smallbox"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="forth-box">
    <div class="box-4-parent">
      <div class="box-4"></div>
      <div class="box-4"></div>
      <div class="box-4"></div>
      <div class="box-4"></div>
      <!-- <div class="box-1"></div>
                <div class="box-1"></div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;

  console.log(`The viewport's width is ${width} and the height is ${height}`);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**I want this type of result:** Which can give the right result on every screen. (Use HTML and CSS only)

[image]